# Code coverage "Unknown" using jest 15.1.1

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

When I try to include all the project source code to get a more reasonable code coverage figure, I end up with

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

My config contains the following:

```
"collectCoverageFrom": [
    "<rootDir>/app_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/src/"
],
```

I've also tried it without the trailing `/`, with `**/*.js` and with just a trailing `*.js` all to no avail.

Based on the `--debug` option, the path expands to the paths I want to collect coverage information from ( isn't the problem)

So what is the magic to getting more accurate coverage information?

The best docs I've been able to find come from this Github PR:  https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/1349/files

---

I ended up doing:

```
"collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.js",
    "!webpack.config.js"
],
```

which only worked because this is part of the default config

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
],
```

It does add a huge amount of time to the test run though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at your link very carefully:

```
collectCoverageFrom: {
  description: wrap(
    'relative to <rootDir> glob pattern matching the files that coverage ' +
      'info needs to be collected from.'
      ...
```

You can't use `<rootDir>`. Try:

```
collectCoverageFrom: [
    "**/app_modules/**",
    "**/src/**"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an other information to add to your edited question: instead of declaring a second array:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
],
```

You can just keep using your `collectCoverageFrom` array by prepending `!` to the directory you do not want to collect coverage information about:

```
collectCoverageFrom: [
    "!**/node_modules/**"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just force de coverage with the option forceCoverageMatch : ['**/*.ts','***/.js']